# Can you close all open windows in capybara?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

So when I run my tests individually, they work great. However, when I run my feature (multiple tests) my code is failing.
This is because when capybara exists, not all of my windows are closing and therefore my selenium drivers don't know which window to use.

Basically, what is happening is that my test is opening multiple windows. This is happening because my tests are clicking links which open new windows and checking the content in the new windows. Even though I am saying `page.quit` at the end of each test, this function isn't closing all open windows (closes active window but not the original window). When the 2nd test runs, it uses the originally create window, but when it goes to open the new pop up, it uses the wrong window.

How can I ensure that a new browser is being used during each test and all windows from the previous test are closed.
I am currently using `page.reset!` and `page.quit`.
Not sure, but can I say `session.quit` to close all open browser windows?

Answer (score 8):

This code works:

```
page.execute_script "window.close();"
```

I just execute this while in the window I want to close.

Comment: This code doesn't work if you are using a plugin like dirty forms, and have a dirty form on the screen, in that case the javascript pops up an "are you sure" alert and the page is not closed. Much better to do "page.reset!" before you run the test.

Comment: `page.execute_script "window.close();"` does not work for me. Should be without the `;`, i.e. `page.execute_script "window.close()"`

Answer (score 4):

I use this code piece to access popups and close them after. It should not be much difference

```
within_window(page.driver.browser.window_handles.last) do
  click buttons and stuff...
  ...
  page.driver.browser.close #closes popup
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This does not work because all resources are lost and the 2nd test fails saying "browser not found" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

```
page.driver.browser.window_handles.each do |handle|
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(handle)
  page.execute_script "window.close()"

end
```

Did the charm for me. Combination of @Jason and @Justin's answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
page.driver.browser.window_handles.each do |handle|
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(handle)
  page.quit
end
```

(I think it will work, but I have not had a chance to test it.)

Comment: This will not work, 'quit' function doesn't exist. Same with Close.

Comment: This works randomly though. This time it gave me `Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchWindowError:
       getUrl execution failed;
        The window could not be found`

Comment: quit function is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tab_id = page.driver.find_window("http://google.com.au")
page.driver.browser.switch_to.window(tab_id)
page.driver.quit
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have all assertions in spec file, I **passed control** to **new page (window)**, after executing assertions I **closed** new page and **passed control** to original page as bellow:

```
after(:each) do
  expect(@static_page.has_logo?).to eq(true) # assertion in new page
  page.execute_script('window.close()') # close new page
  switch_to_window(windows.first) # return control to first page
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this here because this page comes up within the first few Google results for "capybara close all windows".

We had some mysterious feature spec failures that we tracked down to a few that opened app links in second tabs -- since the tabs were just left open, every so often they'd fire a failing AJAX request and the current test would bomb out with a completely unrelated error. The way we fixed that was to add a hook that made sure to close all but the current window after every feature spec:

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.after(type: :feature) do
    # Make sure all browser windows except one are closed
    windows.reject(&:current?).each(&:close)
  end
end
```

This worked like a charm for us, using Capybara's `headless_chrome` driver.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your feature tests, it'll reset the session cookies and start the test on a blank page:

```
# Window washing - use a clean window before every example
before(:example) do
  page.reset!
end
```